# How to call a void method from .DLL file and connect it to WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

so I have a .DLL file with this method:

```
public Class1
{
    public void ProjectList()
    {
        try
        {
            var srv = new ProjectService(ApiToken);
            var obj = srv.List();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
    }
}
```

What it does it gets all the project details(listing) from a `WEB` site. It works because I've tested it when it was an `EXE` application (now it's `.DLL`). Now my executable application is `WPF` with a `Button` and a `ListBox`. I need to get the project data via that method on `Button_Click` but I'm unable to connect it to my ListBox. I guess I don't know how to call it and connect the project listing with my `ListBox`.

If I write, in my `EXE` application something like `listbox1.Items.Add(Class1.ProjectList());` it wont work because I guess it has to loop through the items.....and I get the error `"Cannot implicitly convert type void to System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection"`

EDIT: In my `Console` application I use it like this:

```
public static void ProjektList()
    {

            var srv = new ProjectService(ApiToken);


            var obj = srv.List();
            for (int i = 0; i <= obj.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj[i]);
            }


        }
```

And it works fine. When I turn it into `IEnumerable` and in `DLL` :

```
public IEnumerable ProjektList()
    {

            var srv = new ProjectService(ApiToken);


            var obj = srv.List();
            return obj;


        }
```

And then I'm calling it in my WPF application:

```
 private void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        listb.ItemsSource =  c.ProjektList();

    }
```

In my `Console` application it works fine, I get listing of my projects. But If I debug it in `WPF` application I get that the list is empty, `Count=0`;

Comment: Are you sure that ApiToken has the correct value? You need to do some debugging. Nothing obviously wrong with the code we see here.

Comment: ApiToken has the correct value if it hadn't then also Console application wouldn't be able to get the data ( to authenticate user)

Comment: What was the problem? Have you found out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare you method to return the data you want it to return and then actually return that data.

```
public Class1
{
    public IEnumerable ProjectList()
    {
        try
        {
            var srv = new ProjectService(ApiToken);
            var obj = srv.List();

            // Return the list to the caller
            return obj;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
    }
}
```

Then in the caller code, you can assign:

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = Class1.ProjectList();
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. It does nothing and if I debug it it says the `ItemsSource Count` is `0`. But if I do the same only in `Console` application and loop through the list with `for` loop it lists all projects in the Console window.

Comment: Show us the complete source code of both your console application and your attempt to use the dll.